# Problem to realize a specific regex filter for Fail2ban service

Tags: regex, fail2ban

I can't find the good regex to match the element that i want to identify

example of my log file to analyze :

```
[20190625-10:20:20] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.1.32 port 52166
[20190625-10:19:22] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login failed for display 0
[20190625-10:20:20] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.1.32 port 52166
[20190625-10:20:20] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.1.32 port 52167
[20190625-10:21:19] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.1.32 port 52176
[20190625-10:21:19] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.1.32 port 52177
```

I want to find the regex to detect a line of this style :

```
[20190625-11:47:51] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.1.32 port 55737
```

I have tested `failregex = ^.*ffff:<HOST> port *$`

```
Not ok


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:

Lines: 6 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 6 missed
[processed in 0.01 sec]

|- Missed line(s):
|  [20190625-10:20:20] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.1.32 port 52166
|  [20190625-10:19:22] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login failed for display 0
|  [20190625-10:20:20] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.1.32 port 52166
|  [20190625-10:20:20] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.1.32 port 52167
|  [20190625-10:21:19] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.1.32 port 52176
|  [20190625-10:21:19] [INFO ] A connection received from: ::ffff:192.168.1.32 port 52177
```

Comment: Like this [`^.*ffff:.*?port \d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/yiwHLZ/1/)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about it, just guessing that we might want an expression similar to:

```
(\[[0-9]{8}.+?A connection received from: ::ffff:.+?port\s+[0-9]+)
```

with an `s` flag.

[Please see the demo for additional explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/XD3njZ/1/)